# Laravel regulate number of request per admin

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hello I am building a laravel app whereby users apply for a task via a form. 
Now I want these task to be equally shared between admins for processing such that no two admins have the same task. Example if there are 100 request from users and 2 admins, each admin should see 50 of the request. 
What's the best approach to go about this? My current setup is such that each admin can see all the request. I want the system to automatically assign request to admins.

Comment: Assign requests?

Comment: When a user applies for a task, they are basically sending a request which can either be approved or rejected by an admin.

Comment: With requests are you referring to HTTP calls or your application logic allowed intents?

Comment: I mean application logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming a few things as mentioned below:

- By request, you meant that 'x' entry is created in 'y' table upon successful request by each user.
- You can have 'n' numbers of admin and the 'x' entry could be assigned to any and only one admin.

I will list down the explanation of how it can be done:

1. Fetch all requests from 'y' table where admin_id is null. You can use Laravel's [whereNull](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses). You can perform the fetch via [result chunking](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#chunking-results).
2. Get the list of all admins present in the DB along with there requests' count. Can be done via Laravel's [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method.
3. Now you can traverse through each 'x' entry from 'y' table and assign it to an admin. Remember to increase the count of that particular admin.

There are several ways to implement it now:

1. Soln 1: You can perform the request as soon as it comes but that could add an unnecessary overhead of slowing the request.
2. Soln 2: You can write [artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan) command and use a [task scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling) to run the command every 2-3 hour or any time that you like.

Comment: Thank you. I will try implementing this write away.